# How to import a UML pattern in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm new to using EA, and I am wondering how I can import a GoF pattern. I have found this seemingly outdated procedure to import the UML pattern.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/developers/import_uml_patterns.html

and the UML patterns seem to be here as well:

http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/developers/uml_patterns.htm

Can someone give me better instructions on how to do this. When I try to follow the instructions it tells me to "Switch to the Project Resource tab." which I don't see, I also don't an "Import UML Pattern" option. These instructions are all using seemingly non-existent options (in the latest Enterprise Architect).

Answer (score 0):

The Project Resources tab is accessed in the Project menu (Alt-6).

I can't remember now if the GoF patterns are bundled with all editions of EA but if they're not, you should be able to download them from Sparx' site.

*Applying* a pattern is simply a matter of dragging it onto a diagram from the Resources tab; some diagram toolboxes also include relevant patterns.